# Using `push_back()` with multidimensional vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, multidimensional-array

Say, for a MWE, I have a some code like:

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<long int> > > pooHistory;
pooHistory pHist (1, vector<vector<long int>>(1, vector<long int>(1,0)));
```

that kept track of, for example:

- The number of dogs
- The number of times each dog defecates
- The position of each defecation.

While I'm trying to create new dogs, defecations and coordinated I run into some issues.
I can create new defecations with

`pooHist.walkHist.back().push_back(std::vector<long int>(dimensions,0));`

For some clarification, this inserts an array with 2 indices in the third dimension for x and y coordinates. (In the actual implementation, the number of dimensions is variable. These dogs defecate on number lines, in quadrants, octants and any orthant you like!)

But I can't seem to create new dogs.
I tried something akin to
`pooHist.pushback(std::vector<std::vector<long int>>(1))`, but this created a new defecation with space for only 1 coordinate.

Which does simplify my code a little, since that teaches me that
`pooHist.pushback(std::vector<std::vector<long int>>(dimensions))` should also create new defecations... but I digress.

I'm not sure how to create a new dog, with 1 new defecation and with dimension-number coordinate slots awaiting a new defecation.

Comment: Something not related to your actual question: `pooHist.size()` is the exact type accepted by the `vector::at` function so your cast to `unsigned long int` is both unnecessary and wrong. And you can simply use `vector::back`.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed both of those. I had tried `std::vector::back`  before but I implemented it wrong. Now I just need to figure out the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! I figured it out!

To simplify things, I declared

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<long int> > columnVec;
typedef std::vector<long int> rowVec;
```

And then used std::vector::push_back and std::vector:resize as such:

```
pooHist.back().push_back(rowVec(0));
walkHist.back().back().resize(dimensions,0);

pooHist.push_back(columnVec(0));
walkHist.back().resize(1);
```

The first two lines create a new defecation list, the last two lines create a new defication and size it with n-dimensions.
Everything is initialized to zero.

Answer (score 1):

I think your choice of data structure for your `pooHistory` is causing the confusion. A map of dog to location of defecation should suffice. So to store that all you need is:

`std::map< std::string, std::vector< location > > pooHistory;`

where `location` is `struct location { double lat; double lon; };`. The first template parameter of map is a `std::string` since it denotes the dog's name. If you chose to have an integer id, then you can change that to `int`.

The number of times each dog defecated is simply `pooHistory["dog-name"].second.size()`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: As I stated in the question, the number of dimensions is not known before run time. It could be lat and lon, it could be x,y,z, it could be one dimensional rays, etc. Also the dogs don't actually have names ;). This code is a MWE. 

The place where I state that it should work for n-dimensions is in the parentheses: "In the actual implementation, the number of dimensions is variable. These dogs defecate on number lines, in quadrants, octants and any orthant you like!"

Comment: They you should create a `Location`class to handle those runtime defined coordinates and create a map `std::map<DogId, Location>`. Do not clutter your top level data structure with gory details.

Comment: You can't dynamically create a struct... I'd have to make new doubles for n-dimensional coordinates.

Comment: @NictraSavios: Doesn't `location* p = new location();` create an instance of `location` dynamically? If your `location` is a n-dimensional vector then model it accordingly. I'm not sure what your reference frame is, for locations on earth all you need is a lat/lon or x, y, z if you are using cartesian co-ordinates (which makes n <= 3).

Comment: But where in my questions do I specific that I am on earth? Using cartesian? Or any assumptions at all? The program can actually handle field theory and spherical coordinates and should be valid for up to 11 dimensions, but making it n-dimensional makes more sense in the application. (since 11 is rather arbitrary currently.)
Yes, you have created another location, but not another dimension.